# Does Android4.4 supports TCP Fast Open

Tags: android, tcp

I heard that it's based on linux 3.10 while TFO was completely integrated in 3.7, so anyone knows if Android 4.4 supports TFO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android 4.4 does not support TCP fast open.